# UIImagePickerController needs access to photos in iOS6?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I normally use the `ALAssets` library to access photos and display them, but I wanted to provide the user with an alternative in case they didn't feel comfortable giving access to location data. I installed the `UIImagePicker`, and while it still works fine on iOS5, I noticed on iOS6, when I shut off access to the photos in my app, I get "This app does have access to your photos or videos". Does the `UIImagePickerController` no long allow non disputed access to the photos?

Comment: Refer This Link :- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Accessing_the_iPhone_Camera_and_Photo_Library_(iOS_6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter which route you take to access the photos, if the user has denied access then none of the options will be permitted to access the photos. The authorisation messages may be a little misleading but the same permissions apply to both access methods.

Comment: If the user manually denies access by going to the settings and shutting them off this happens. But what if they haven't, and the user invokes the UIImagePickerController for the first time, will the UIImagePickerController query them about photo access before allowing access?

Comment: Wow suprised by this. Still get negative reviews from users, and even have had some developers questioning me on it. But you're right, in iOS6 the UIImagePicker needs access too!